# сделать проверку на пустое поле js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="panel-body sumLabel">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><span class="error_color">* </span><?php echo $text_sum; ?></label>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="sum_" class="form-control radius sum">
       <div class="error_color" id="errorSum"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

проверка на пустое значения

```
if (sum.length < 1) {
    $('#errorSum').text('Укажите сумму');
    return false
} else {
    $('#errorSum').text('');
}
```

Но у меня есть кнопка скрыть которая скрывает это поле

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.payment_method').click(function () {
       if($(this).val() === "cod_8" || $(this).val() === "cod_9") {
           $(".sumLabel").css("display", "none");
       } else {
           $(".sumLabel").css("display", "block");
       }
   });
});
```

И это поле остается пустым Как сделать проверку с учетом скрытого поля ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").on('input', function(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (!value.length) {
      $("#errorSum").text('Укажите сумму');
    } else {
      $('#errorSum').text('');
    }
  });

  $('#hide').on('click', function() {
    $("#input").toggleClass("input_hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.input {
  display: block;
}

.input_hidden {
  display: none;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label>Input</label>
    <input id='input' class="input" type="number" name="sum">
  </div>
  <div class="error" id="errorSum">Укажите сумму</div>
  <button id="hide">hide field</button>
</div>
```